# Use IF in a SQL view

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am wanting to create a view that calls a table-valued function. I want to use an `IF functionX IS NOT NULL` then proceed with the rest of the view. So far I can get it to work with a stored procedure which is awesome but the software I am writing this for can apparently not call a stored procedure. So i either need to place that stored procedure inside of a view OR create a view with an IF or CASE WHEN.

Here is my stored procedure with the function call, how can I nestle this into a view or turn it into a view? Whenever I try i get an incorrect syntax error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[doSomething]
AS

WITH Events AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM taP1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN taP2 ON taP1.Id = taP2.Id
    WHERE (taP1.ADate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,3,GETDATE()) AND  
    DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())) 
)
    IF  dbo.GetCapacity2('X1') = 1 --FUNCTION
SELECT TOP 100
    taM.Name AS Name,
    taM.TypeId AS MediaTypeId,
    taMS.Name AS SetName,
    taD.Directory AS Directory,
    taMI.Filename AS Filename

FROM taMedia
    INNER JOIN taMI ON taM.Id = taMI.Id
    INNER JOIN taMS ON taMI.SetId = taMSet.SetId
    INNER JOIN taD ON taMI.Id = taD.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN taMU ON taM.Name = taMU.MediaName
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Events ON taM.Name = Events.Name
WHERE taMS.Name = 'X1'
    AND taMU.MUId IS NULL 
    AND Events.Name IS NULL
    ORDER BY taM.Name
    ELSE return;

   GO
```

Comment: a view is just a saved select statement, essentially. It can't contain any conditional logic like that. That's what a stored procedure is for...as you have discovered :-) You can't "proceed with the rest of the view" as you put it, because the view can only consist of one single SELECT statement. If you didn't run that SELECT, there wouldn't _be_ a view.

Comment: So the view should only return rows if `dbo.GetCapacity2('X1') = 1`? Just add `AND dbo.GetCapacity2('X1') = 1` to the end of your `select`. Forget about your IF statement. Your view must always return a bunch of columns but it doesn't have to return any rows. Please explain what the object calling this is trying to do.

Comment: I think it would be more future proof to invent the time to make the application able to call the procedures

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will try that. This object finds files to delete based on the criteria in that view and that function checks for free space on the server. When free space is X we select 100 items to delete.

Answer (score 0):

look on the sample down below. You can create view with 'if' statement as you need, but place your condition in WHERE. It should work as you want.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReturnTrue
()
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
GO

CREATE TABLE TableTmp (Id Int)
Insert Into TableTmp Values (1), (2), (4), (8), (16)
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewTmp]
AS
SELECT TOP 100
    *
FROM 
    TableTmp T
WHERE 
    T.Id > 1
    AND 
    dbo.ReturnTrue() = 1
GO

Select * 
From [dbo].[ViewTmp]
Go
```